# Eiffel studio whats the shortest way to put a breakpoint on current line I'm editing

Tags: breakpoints, eiffel

In Eiffel studio it seems like in the editor basic text view there is no possibility to add a breakpoint.

The only way I found to add a breakpoint on a line I'm editing is

1. change to flat view
2. Scroll again to my function because the scroll went anywhere
3. Put my break point

This behaviour makes me loose a lot of time when I'd like to debug something, maybe anybody has a better way....

Whats the shortest way to put a breakpoint on current line I'm editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a *Feature* tool (*View* | *Tools* | *Feature* - do not confuse with *Features*) where you can drop your feature. It is not associated with the editor window and can be manipulated separately. The *Feature* tool, like the editor window, has several views, one of them is *Flat view* (the second icon from the left). Here, you will see the feature alone and can set a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

As @AlexanderKogtenkov commented

1. Compile
2. Pin the Feature view to be always open (red icon)
   [image]
3. Drag the feature you're writting into the feature tool
4. Click the breakpoint to enable it on sidebar
   [image]

**Note:** Quite complex instead of clicking on the left bar inside the code...